# How to get what element was clicked by disregarding dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I'm trying to create a color picker and have run into a massive issue. Say for example I want to click on a div behind some text to change it's color, I won't be able to do this because the text will override the bg. What can I do here to make it so I can click the element without including the dom box that all elements have?

Comment: can you elaborate your question with code and screenshots is not clear what are you trying to ask, and apparently is an issue more about your logic than the dom

Comment: @ncubica Take a look at updated post.

Comment: Delegate the click event to _bg div_ if the text is within it. Otherwise delegate to `<body>` and watch all clicks. If they originate from an approved source, get the color. Or something along those lines.

Comment: you can use `pointer-events:none` on the element with the text. It will make that element ignore all mouse/pointer events (*`click`,`mouseover`,`mouseleave`,`mouseenter` etc*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I don't want it to ignore the text though, I would like to be able to change the text color also via click .

Comment: You could select the color on click... give a delay time, if the color isn't "selected" and the focused DOM element does not contain a background color, then set as possible color the one, on the container (parent). well is a start...

Comment: i see. Then something like what @hungerstar mentioned. Delegate to the top container, and then while the event bubbles to all the parents check if they match the colorpicker restrictions (*background or text*) and then stop the bubbling of the event and handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running `stopPropagation()` it will only select the clicked element.

```
$(".ColorCardBackgroundView").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById('ColorCardBackground').jscolor.show();
});
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question or a comment?

Comment: This is an answer, it did exactly what i needed.

Comment: You must have `.ColorCardBackgroundView` elements nested within each other then?

Comment: Yes, the children are nested.

Comment: Okay, was wondering why `e.stopPropgation()` would be necessary if they weren't nested. Since they are nested, using it makes sense.
In the future your question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).